# ASP.NET Core: Problem binding model to a multiple Select List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a web application where I am handling related data, I create a Referral Entity that contains between other attributes a Patient, a Requester and different Consultants for this referral. I also have Patient, Requester and Consultant models.

I have been able to use a select list for the Patient and Requester, they have a 1:n relationship with the Referral entity. However, I'm having problems with Consultants, as they have an n:m relationship I'm using a multiple list, I'm able to show my consultant list and pick multiple ones but when I post the data it's not binding to ReferralConsultants and I'm losing it.

This is the [get] Edit action of the referral controller.

```cs
var referral = await _context.Referral
                .Include(r => r.Patient)
                .Include(r => r.Requester)
                .Include(r => r.ReferralConsultants)
                    .ThenInclude(r => r.Consultant)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.ID == id);

            if (referral == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["Patients"] = new SelectList(_context.Patient, "ID", "FullName", referral.PatientID);
            ViewData["Requesters"] = new SelectList(_context.Requester, "ID", "FullName", referral.RequesterID);
            var consultants =  from c in _context.Consultant
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ConsultantID = c.ID,
                                        c.FullName
                                    };

            ViewData["Consultants"] = new MultiSelectList(consultants, "ConsultantID", "FullName", referral.ReferralConsultants);
            return View(referral);
```

This is my View

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Patient Information</h3>
                <label asp-for="PatientID" class="control-label">Patient</label>
                <select asp-for="PatientID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Patients"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="PatientID" class="text-danger"></span>


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Requester Information</h3>
                <label asp-for="RequesterID" class="control-label">Requester</label>
                <select asp-for="RequesterID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Requesters"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="RequesterID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

....            

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReferralConsultants" class="control-label">Consultants</label>
                <select asp-for="ReferralConsultants" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Consultants"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ReferralConsultants" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is [post] Edit action

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,PatientID,RequesterID,DateIssued,DateRequested,Description,Type,ReferralConsultants")] Referral referral)
        {
            if (id != referral.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(referral);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ReferralExists(referral.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
```

And these are the models:

```cs
public class Referral
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int PatientID { get; set; }
        public int RequesterID { get; set; }

       ....

        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
        public Requester Requester { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ReferralConsultant> ReferralConsultants { get; set; }
    }


    public class ReferralConsultant
    {
        [Key]
        public int ConsultantID { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int ReferralID { get; set; }

        public Referral Referral { get; set; }
        public Consultant Consultant { get; set; }
    }

    public class Consultant : Person
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ReferralConsultant> ReferralConsultants { get; set; }
    }

    public class Patient : Person
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int PatientID { get; set; }

        ...

        public ICollection<Referral> Referrals { get; set; }
    }
```

The only thing I'm missing is being able to know which Consultants have been selected when I'm in the [post] Edit action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the issue doing the following:

I create the MultiSelectList item and send it to the view like this.

ReferralsController.cs

```cs
var consultants =  from c in _context.Consultant
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ConsultantID = c.ID,
                                        c.FullName
                                    };

            ViewData["Consultants"] = new MultiSelectList(consultants, "ConsultantID", "FullName", referral.ReferralConsultants.Select(r => r.ConsultantID).ToArray());
            return View(referral);
```

In the View

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label d-inline">
                    Consultants
        <select multiple name="selectedValues" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Consultants"></select>
        </label>
   </div>
```

This will send the selectedValues to my controller when I submit the form. Then I just need to get those values in my Edit [Post] and save them in the Database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,PatientID,RequesterID,DateIssued,DateRequested,Description,Type, Status")] Referral referral, string [] selectedValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Referral` model, change the type of `ReferralConsultants` to `ICollection<int>` (or whatever the type of `Consultant.ID` is), as for select elements only the value (`ConsultantID` in this case) is included in the form submit. This gets clear if you inspect the generated source of the view in the browser.
See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-select-tag-helper) for further information.

Comment: Thank you for the information and sorry for the late reply. I wanted to keep the ICollection<Consultant> in my model so I work out the solution I posted.